# NameError: name 'sv' is not defined while importing python module

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, nameerror

I am facing a problem in python. Tho the error is quite common, but since i am bit new to python, unable to comprehend the source hence asking you all. There are 2 modules: session.py and objects.py.

session.py

```
import copy
import pymongo
import spacy
import tweepy

import objects
```

objects.py:

```
import re

def refresh (sv = sv, obj = ''):
    return 0
```

now, in python shell, i am getting the error before even executing objects.py:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "session.py", line 6, in <module>
    import objects
  File "objects.py", line 3, in <module>
    def refresh (sv = sv, obj = ''):
NameError: name 'sv' is not defined
>>>
```

I came from perl background to maybe missing some very common thing, but still i am able to do this:

```
>>> def ff(t): print t
...
```

In above, whitout defining t, it is working while in objects.py, how can i define sv without starting execution?

Comment: the problem is in `def refresh(sv=sv <--` sv is undeclared.

Comment: Yes, i know sv is undeclared, but how can i declare it beforehand. I mean, what i plan to do is somethng like:
sv = session.setup()
 and within session, objects.refresh will be called with the variable. 

As i understand, the sv will be needed only if i do not pass any variable (as in sv will be taken from globals during execution and not import).

But still let me try out removing all such refrences

Comment: before `def refresh`, by the way your function is just returning 0 not using any of the required arguments

Comment: Even defining sv did not helped:
```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sv = {'a': 'b'}
>>> import session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "session.py", line 6, in <module>
    import objects
  File "objects.py", line 3, in <module>
    def refresh (sv = sv, obj = ''):
NameError: name 'sv' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: you have to define it in the same file `objects.py`

Comment: >>> before def refresh, by the way your function is just returning 0 not using any of the required arguments

YEs actually, i just copied the skeleton of the function here. Actually i most certainly plan to use it :)

Comment: Thanks buddy, resolved it by defining sv in objects.py file. But followup question: "Is it mandatory to initialize a parameter which is being passed to a function even before import"? I mean the "def ff(t): print t" works fine even before defining "t"
Thanks again a lot for your help :)

Comment: why not just use def refresh (sv,obj):